# Why does this onclick event not work?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have mad a image, with this onclick event

```
onclick="document.getElementById('custom-select span').style.border-bottom-radius ='0px';"
```

Comment: First question -- do you understand the difference between Java and Javascript? That's kind of key if you want to direct your question to the right folk who can actually help you.

Comment: not really, i am only 15, i thought they were the same.

Comment: Java and Javascript about as similar as ham is to hamburger -- similar names, both based on a C-like syntax, but that's about it. You'll want to use javascript tags in the future for your javascript questions, else you'll have folks like me looking at it who don't know shoot about this language. Luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`border-bottom-radius` is not a valid identifier in JavaScript. Use `borderBottomRadius` instead.

Besides that, is your element's ID really `custom-select span` with the space?! You shouldn't put spaces in IDs - they are not valid there so it might cause problems in some browsers.

Comment: You have jQuery. Don't use those ugly inline events but register the events using jQuery! And `borderbottomradius` is not `borderBottomRadius` - those properties are case-sensitive...